# Why isn't document.execCommand causing the clipboard to populate?

Tags: javascript, html, css, clipboard

I have the following HTML:

```
<td class="pn">
  <span class="copyable">410-555-1234</span>
  <span title="Click to copy" class="clipboard">&#x1f4cb;</span>
  <form class="pn-copy-form">
    <input class="pn-copy" type="text" value="+14105551234" />
  </form>
</td>
```

When the user clicks on the clipboard icon, I would like to populate the contents of the user's system clipboard with "+14105551234". However, I notice that nothing populates. Here's the Javascript I'm using, placed at the bottom of the same page:

```
  var evHandler = function(clipboardElem) {
    return function() {
      var pnCopy = clipboardElem.parentNode.querySelector('.pn-copy');
      if (pnCopy === null) {
        return;
      }
      pnCopy.select();
      try {
        result = document.execCommand('copy');
        if (result === false) {
          throw new Error("Could not copy value: " + pnCopy.value);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        alert("Couldn't copy text, sorry. Here it is: " + pnCopy.value);
      }
      console.log("Copied "+ pnCopy.value + " to the clipboard");
      pnCopy.blur();
    };
  }

  var clipboards = document.querySelectorAll('.clipboard');
  for (var i = 0; i < clipboards.length; i++) {
    var clipboard = clipboards[i];
    clipboard.addEventListener('click', evHandler(clipboard));
  }
```

I'm hiding the form, since I don't want it to appear on the page.

```
.pn-copy {
    display: none;
}
```

Why isn't the clipboard populating? Does click-to-copy not work on localhost, or not work on unencrypted HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form needs to be "visible," though that definition is loose, and I think is roughly "not display:none". Without that in place, `.select()` selects no text. I had success with the following CSS, which leaves the input "visible" but placed 3000 pixels off screen.

```
/* the input has to be "visible", if you use display: none copy won't work. */
.pn-copy-form {
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    left: -3000px;
}
```